# Onsubmit not executing

Tags: javascript, html

onsubmit does not execute in the code snippet below when you press the submit button. It should show 'Submitting' in the javascript console when you press Submit.

```js
function submit(v) {
  console.log('Submitting');
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="submit()">
<input type=submit />
</form>
```

Comment: It does, as soon as you choose a different name for your function. (The `form` element has a `submit` method by default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a name collision. Name your function something other than `submit`, it worked for me then.

See below:

```js
function a () {
  console.log('Submitting');
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="a()">
<input type=submit />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`submit()` is a predefined method in javaScript which submits a form. Just rename it to another name.

```js
function submit2(v) {
  console.log('Submitting');
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="submit2()">
<input type=submit />
</form>
```